# Git computes for minutes then says "not a git repository"

Tags: git

I've got something very weird going on with my git repo. When I run `git status`, it runs for minutes at a time, then gives the following error as if giving up:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I cloned the remote repo in a separate directory, checked it with `git status` (`nothing to commit`, as expected), then copied in all the files from the original directory *other than* the `.*` files (like `.git`). In theory, all the changed files copied in. Now:

```
% git status
(...minutes pass...)
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Check to make sure all the correct files are still there:

```
% ls -a
.dockerignore 
.DS_Store
.git  
.gitignore  
.gitmodules  
.idea  
src  
Dockerfile  
Dockerfile.dev    
LICENSE.md
README.md
```

I re-cloned the repo, `git status` working as expected, again copied in all the files that don't start with a dot, now `git status` takes minutes and then gives the above error.

---

### Edit with Answers to Comments

> Is .git a file or directory? Are you trying to run the git commands whilst inside .git? *(@evolutionxbox)*

```
% ls .git
FETCH_HEAD  config      hooks       info        objects
HEAD        description index       logs        refs
```

> Perhaps there is a .git folder somewhere in the src directory? Something must be throwing git off. *(@Gimby)*

```
% find . -name '.gi*'

./src/.gitignore
./.gitmodules
./.gitignore
./.git
./.idea/.gitignore
```

Comment: Is `.git` a file or directory? Are you trying to run the git commands whilst inside `.git`?

Comment: Perhaps there is a .git folder somewhere in the src directory? Something must be throwing git off.

Comment: @Gimby of course there is, he's using submodules.

Comment: ... right. so just copying over directories from somewhere else probably doesn't work too well then.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Added my check to the question. It's a directory, and I'm not inside it

Comment: @Gimby Added answer to question

Comment: Maybe a (large) submodule is *missing* a `.git`. What’s in `.gitmodules`?